# Android ICS compiling MacOsx lion

Tags: android, osx-lion

Hi i am trying to build android source code on Mac OS Lion. When i run make it throws a million errors. Trace is available at http://pastebin.com/FfZEsycs. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You must follow the steps described in [Setting up a Mac OS X build environment](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html).

Comment: i did but when compiling it throws errors. i have crated pastebin link for errors.

Comment: gcc 4.2. Version 4.x could cause difficulties